# Data controlled programs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, dictionary

Not to sure how to name this question because the problem itself is looking for a construct of which I don´t know its name.

The problem is I am dealing with programs whose control flow depends greatly of data.

For example I created a MIPS simulator which implemented a list of more than 50 instructions, each implemented on its own and everything governed by a huge switch case

```
switch (function){ //Function is an int, each function (eg SLL) is 
        case 0:    //associated with one
            if (state->debug_level > 0){
                fprintf(state->debug_out, "SLL\n");
            }
            step_err = SLL(state, rs, rt, rd, sa);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (state->debug_level > 0){
                fprintf(state->debug_out, "SRL\n");
            }
            step_err = SRL(state, rs, rt, rd, sa);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (state->debug_level > 0){
                fprintf(state->debug_out, "SRA\n");
            }
//
```

I have been told that this could have been implemented using function pointers, but to do so what I am looking for is a way of relating data of any kind, say a string to other data, say an integer. I am aware of maps but wouldn't want to push back each pair. I am looking for some sort of array like syntax I think if seen before which might look something similar to this:

```
¿type? function_codes[]{
     0, "SLL";
     2, "SRL";
     3, "SRA";
     ...
 }
```

I am not looking for a solution to this problem but a generic approach to introducing quick relationships between data and using this to modify control flow.

**EDIT AFTER ANSWERS**
What I was actually looking for but I didnt know was indeed maps but in particular its initialization syntax similar to an array (see accepted answer). This used with function pointers did the required job.

Comment: You are looking for a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: Isn't that a `std::array<return_type (*)(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4), max_function> functions` ?

Comment: Data controlling behavior on runtime sounds very similar to language parsing. Might be a bit overkill but have you looked in the direction of BNF parser?

Comment: Although you'd like to have runtime access to this data, it seems that it's all defined at compile time.  Sounds like a job for templates!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you guessed, function pointers are in fact a good way to do this. Since you specify that you don't want to use a Map, this is how you would implement your integer-based function dispatch using an array of function pointers. Note that since I don't know the type signature of your MIPS functions (SLL, SRL, etc.) I've used dummy placeholder type names.

```
typedef ret_t (*mips_func)(arg1_t, arg2_t, arg3_t, arg4_t, arg5_t);

mips_func function_codes[] = {
    &SLL,
    &SRL,
    &SRA,
    ...
};

//...Later, in the part of your code that used to contain the big switch statement
step_err = (*function_codes[function])(state, rs, rt, rd, sa);
```

The syntax `&SLL` gets a pointer to the function SLL, which I assume is already in scope because you can call it directly from your switch statement.

Note that this assumes the numeric codes for the functions are a continuous sequence of integers from 0 to [max code value]. If some numeric codes are unused, then you will either need to leave explicit gaps in your array (by placing a NULL pointer in one or more entries) or use `std::map<int, mips_func>` so that you can use arbitrary non-continuous integer values as keys to functions. Fortunately, using a Map still doesn't require `push_back`ing each element, since C++ now has initializer lists. The same code using a Map would look like this:

```
typedef ret_t (*mips_func)(arg1_t, arg2_t, arg3_t, arg4_t, arg5_t);

std::map<int, mips_func> function_codes = {
    {0, &SLL},
    {2, &SRL},
    {4, &SRA},
    ...
};

//Using the Map looks exactly the same, due to its overloaded operator[]
step_err = (*function_codes[function])(state, rs, rt, rd, sa);
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, kept simple as well so thanks! I'll edit my question to give some more precise info to next viewers

Answer (score 3):

For simplify you can use associative containers. If the order is important then use `std::map`, or `std::unordered_map` in the other case.

And you can use syntax similar to the desired

```
std::map<size_t, std::string> codes_map = decltype(codes_map) {
    { 0, "val1" },
    { 1, "val2" }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Besides, OP explicitly said he doesn't want to use maps.

Comment: Sure, you're right. But on the other hand it's possible to use the selected syntax with maps, like `std::map<std::string, std::string> codes_map = decltype(codes_map){ {"key1", "val1"}, {"key2", "val2"} };`

Comment: @Edward No, OP said " I am aware of maps but wouldn't want to push back each pair" - and **they don't have to** since we have `initializer_list` syntax in this modern age and can specify a map in effectively the exact format dreamt of at the end of their post. This very much _does_ answer the question. +1

Comment: it is actually what I was looking for, sorry for the missundertanding with the maps, I meant I didnt want to pushback each individual member, because I wasn't aware of this syntax. I accept another similar answer since it is more complete but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could group the data as static members w/ the same name across structs, then use templates to access them generically:

```
struct A { auto call() const { return "((1))"; };  static const char * name; };
struct B { auto call() const { return "{{2}}"; };  static const char * name; };
struct C { auto call() const { return "<<3>>"; };  static const char * name; };
// n.b. these `T...` have: `sizeof(T) == ... == sizeof(empty_struct)`

const char * A::name = "A";
const char * B::name = "B";
const char * C::name = "C";
```

[`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) (and the soon to be implemented [`std::variant`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4542.pdf)) implements a type-safe union, which provides a very clean and efficient way of using these structs as values:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::variant<A, B, C>> letters{A{}, B{}, C{}, B{}, A{}};
    auto visitor = [](auto x) { std::printf("%s(): %s\n", x.name, x.call()); };
    for (auto var : letters) { boost::apply_visitor(visitor, var); }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/461adc56ca565639)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small number of indices to support, from 0 to 50, you'll get the best performance if you put your function pointers in an array and not a map.

The syntax is also short:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

static void f0() {
    std::cout << "f0\n";
}

static void f1() {
    std::cout << "f1\n";
}

void main()
{
    std::function<void()> f[2] = { f0, f1 };

    f[0](); // prints "f0"
    f[1](); // prints "f1"
}
```

Or, if you prefer classes over functions:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class myfunc {
public:
    virtual void run() abstract;
    virtual ~myfunc() {}
};

class f0 : public myfunc {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        std::cout << "f0\n";
    }
};

class f1 : public myfunc {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        std::cout << "f1\n";
    }
};


void main()
{
    myfunc* f[2] = { new f0(), new f1() };
    f[0]->run(); // prints "f0"
    f[1]->run(); // prints "f1"
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(f) / sizeof(f[0]); ++i)
        delete f[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two problems: the flow-control issue (dispatch) and the map issue (an implementation note). I get that the program flow is nonstatic and unknowable at compile-time… but so is the map static? For static maps I get a lot of mileage out of using a traits-ish approach to create a compile-time mapping. Here’s a quick example mapping file suffixes to Objective-C enum constants:

```
namespace objc {

    namespace image {

        template <std::size_t N> inline
        constexpr std::size_t static_strlen(char const (&)[N]) { return N; }

        template <NSBitmapImageFileType t>
        struct suffix_t;

        #define DEFINE_SUFFIX(endstring, nstype)                                        \
        template <>                                                                     \
        struct suffix_t<nstype> {                                                       \
            static constexpr std::size_t N = static_strlen(endstring);                  \
            static constexpr char const str[N] = endstring;                             \
            static constexpr NSBitmapImageFileType type = nstype;                       \
        };

        DEFINE_SUFFIX("tiff", NSTIFFFileType);
        DEFINE_SUFFIX("bmp",  NSBMPFileType);
        DEFINE_SUFFIX("gif",  NSGIFFileType);
        DEFINE_SUFFIX("jpg",  NSJPEGFileType);
        DEFINE_SUFFIX("png",  NSPNGFileType);
        DEFINE_SUFFIX("jp2",  NSJPEG2000FileType);

        template <NSBitmapImageFileType nstype>
        char const* suffix_value = suffix_t<nstype>::str;

    }
}
```

… see how that works? the nice part is that using it has no runtime overhead, which if your map is static, you can use something like that.

For dynamic flow-control and dispatch, function pointers work; that is what happens automatically if you use polymorphic classes and `virtual` functions but it seems like you have an architecture in place already that may not be amenable to being redone with such high-modernist architectural notions. I like c++11 lambdas as they solve like 90% of my problems in this arena. Perhaps you can elablrate (I will amend my answer)!

Answer (score 0):

Given some definitions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct state{
    int debug_level = 1;
    const char* debug_out = "%s";
} s;

// some functions to call
void SLL(state& s, int, int, int, int){
    cout << "SLL";
}
void SLR(state& s, int, int, int, int){
    cout << "SLR";
}
void SLT(state& s, int, int, int, int){
    cout << "SLT";
}
```

You can use a Map

```
auto mappedname2fn = map<string, delctype(SLL)*>{
    {"SLL", SLL}, 
    {"SLR", SLR}
};

// call a map function
mappedname2fn["SLR"](s, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

If you don't want a map you can use a pre-sorted array for a binary search

Here's a binary search of an array of name, function pairs

```
template<typename P, int N, typename ...T> 
auto callFn(P(&a)[N], string val, T&&... params){
    auto it = lower_bound(a, a+N, make_pair(val, nullptr),
        [](auto& p1, auto& p2){return p1.first < p2.first;});
    if(it==(a+N) || val<it->first) throw logic_error("not found");
    return it->second(forward<T>(params)...);
}
```

So you can set up an array and use that:-

```
// array sorted in alphabetical order for binary search to work
pair<string, decltype(SLL)*> name2fn[] = {
        {"SLL", SLL}, 
        {"SLR", SLR},
        {"SLT", SLT}
    };
void callFn(string name, state& s, int a, int b, int c, int d){
    try{
        callFn(name2fn, name, s, a, b, c, d);
    }
    catch(exception& e){
        cout << e.what();
    }
}

// call it  
callFn("SLL", s, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```